# Improper integral with two problem points

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I need to prove wheter the integral $\int_0^1\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{e^x-1}dx$ converges or diverges. I managed to prove the it diverges for $\alpha = 1$, and for $0<\alpha<1$ it's simple to prove by comparison with the case $\alpha = 1$. But this obviously doesn't work for $\alpha>1$. Any sugestions?

Comment: $\Re\left(\alpha\right) > 1 \implies \texttt{converges}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{e^x-1}=\frac{x}{e^x-1}\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x}\sim x^{\alpha-2}$$

Comment: I get the intuition, but how do I use that to prove it?

Comment: @MathNewbie The rigorous formalization is by limit comparison test, we can say indeed that the given integral behaves as $x^{\alpha-2}$ and thus we can conclude that it converges for $2-\alpha<1 $ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @MathNewbieFor this reason limit comparison test is very powerful, we can estimate the behaviour by asympthotic analisys and then formalize by the test.

Answer (score 1):

Near $0$, we know that
$$e^x-1\sim x $$

thus
$$\frac {x^{\alpha-1}}{e^x-1}\sim x^{\alpha-2}$$

the integral converges iff
$$2-\alpha <1$$
or
$$\alpha>1.$$